# Wireless keyboard and mouse Dell QWERTY older type keyboard. Quarter moon sign Stopped working as a sleepbutton it now turns off the computer

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I have recently downloaded an update from Wndows10.  The quarter moon sign on my Qwerty Keyboard if pressed switches of the computer. It used to act as a sleep button, How do I get it to operate as before My Keyboard does not have an FN button it is an older version  Dell Keyboard .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "Sleep Button" function in Control Panel > Power Options > Change what the power buttons do.

- Start > Windows System > Control Panel (or open File Explorer, place the cursor in the address bar and type "Control Panel" and hit Enter.)
- From Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > Click "Change what the power buttons do"
- On this page, there is a setting that says "When I press the sleep button:", ensure the drop down list is set to "Sleep", then click "Save changes".

That should restore the sleep button on your keyboard to make Windows 10 sleep instead of shutdown.

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/885705/blaelph Thankyou for the help  This worked Ok. I could not find this setting when I searched All the best Steve.